# Where does templated method code get allocated?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, optimization, compilation

(I am using GCC 5.3.0 with LTO enabled)

I have three class methods:

```
void method1(){
    .
    method2();
    .
}

void method2(){
    .
    method3();
    .
}

void method3(){...}
```

and the methods are arranged to maximize cache spatial locality.

I now template method2() and there are two possible templated types, generating two versions of `method2()`.

Will the code/instructions for method2() still be contiguous with method1() and method3() (like below) or are templated methods allocated elsewhere?

```
void method1(){
    .
    method2();
    .
}

template<typename T1>
void method2(){
    .
    method3();
    .
}

template<typename T2>
void method2(){
    .
    method3();
    .
}

void method3(){...}
```

I still want the two templated `method2()`s to be allocated contiguous to `method1()` and `method3()`.

Comment: What makes you think the compiler puts the instructions in the exact order you wrote the code? Even worse, once the optimizer is done with your code (think inlining) there is not much left of your original order. The compiler will put hot code together, the order of declaration is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Very little is guaranteed about how the object code for such functions will be arranged in memory.

You can use `-Wl,-Map=output.map` to generate a map file, which will tell you the addresses the linker has assigned to the various functions (assuming they're generated as discrete functions, not just inline code).

If examination of the map file shows that that locations chosen by the linker by default aren't satisfactory for your needs, there are ways you can force things (but for templates, this can be somewhat non-trivial).

The linker works with sections, so to get control of the function order, you'll need to set the section for each function using a section attribute on the function. Since you're dealing with templates, I'd guess (though I'm not absolutely certain) that you'll need to explicitly instantiate your templates over each type you care about, and use the section attributes on the explicit instantiations.

Then you can write a linker script with a `sections` command to tell it the order in which to arrange the sections in the object when it puts them together into the executable file.

#### References

[Function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)
[Linker sections command](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/sections.html)